# Jquery DataTable Dynamic Pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

How can i configure Jquery DataTable to not load all content on first load

e.g if i have **1000** records, DataTable will load all in first load this can be heavy though. how about loading each content when click on pagination part? Like [This](https://jplist.com/layoutexamples/table-1)

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "xhr.php"
  } );
} );
```

There is ServerSide configuration for alike pagination please let me know, if my question is duplicate just shout out.

Comment: http://mobisoftinfotech.com/resources/blog/web-programming/jquery-datatable-ajax-tutorial-with-example-project/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "deferLoading" attribute:

https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html

Answer (score 0):

Check here full jquery example 
[jquery-datatable-ajax-tutorial-with-example](http://mobisoftinfotech.com/resources/blog/web-programming/jquery-datatable-ajax-tutorial-with-example-project/)

```
var studentTable;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

studentTable = jQuery("#studentListTable").dataTable({
"bJQueryUI" : true,
"sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
"bRetrieve" : true,
"bFilter" : true,
"iDisplayLength": 10,
"bProcessing" : true,
"bServerSide" : false,
"aoColumns" : [ { "bSearchable" : false,"bVisible" : false,
"asSorting" : [ "asc" ] },
{"sWidth" : "20%","bSortable" : true },
{"sWidth" : "20%","bSortable" : true },
{"sWidth" : "20%","bSortable" : true },
{"sWidth" : "20%","bSortable" : true },
{"sWidth" : "20%","bSortable" : true }
]
});

jQuery(".ui-corner-br").addClass("ui-widget-header_custom");
});
```